# How to connect to an SQL Server running in a container in Azure with SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, docker, docker-compose

I have created an app service in Azure using a docker container. The docker-compose.yml file that I uploaded to Azure is:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockercrud:
    image: yogyogi/apps:dc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerCrud/Dockerfile
  sqldata:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=vV5r9tn0M4@
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "1450:1433"
```

So Azure has fetched the image from my docker hub account as stated by the image - `image: yogyogi/apps:dc`

Now I want to connect to my SQL Server, running on the container in Azure, with my SQL Server Management Studio on my local pc. Please tell me how to do it?

There are absolute no tutorials or any docs that states this.

Comment: You **really** shouldn't expose your `sa` password...

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're wanting to run SQL Server (a very IO-intensive system) inside a container in a platform that is IO-constrained? I struggle to imagine a good use-case for using this that wouldn't be better served by using either Sqlite in-container, or Azure SQL (seeming as you're running on Azure anyway). So **why** are you doing this?

Comment: @Dai I am just starting with docker on azure and exploring things there. The point is my mssql server is in docker container (see docker-compose.yml) file. I have to create database in it and tables. So I want to connect to it using my SSMS in my local pc. How to do it??

Comment: You need to configure the firewall to allow your PC to connect to the SQL Server instance running in Docker. I see you have a mapping from port `1450` to `433` so you need to use `yourdockerinstancedomainname:1450` in SSMS.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I could not find where is docker instance name in my azure. Can you help in figuring it how to get it?